# Capturing and Passing string of text from forum thread to another page

Tags: php, vbulletin

I was just wondering if the following was possible.

I would like to place a text link/button on a forum (Vbulletin) thread page, which when clicked, captures the "thread title" or "page title" of the thread the user is currently on and passes that onto another page via the URL. This other page should be able to display the text that was passed through the URL.

This code/script would need to be dynamic and work for any thread on the forum and pass that thread title along to the final page.

For example:
If the user is reading through a forum thread called "How do I get my washing machine to work"  and then clicks the link/button on that page to contact us, the user would get sent to another page where I want the text "How do I get my washing machine to work" displayed again for a personalized experience.

Would something like this be possible? If yes, could you elaborate on how this would need to be setup?

Thanks for looking.

~N

Answer (score 0):

for this title you can attach the id of thread into your from 
a hidden input should do it

```
<input type='hidden' id='2003' >
```

when the form is submitted you passed the id too . so you can query the title of this id out of the database . 
if you do want to have the title in url do the get method and dynamically attach the title in form action

```
<form action="some.php?title=<?php echo $title ?>" method="get">
```